# Question migrated from SuperUser?

Tags: discussion

How come this [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/sharepoint-2010-wiki-include-content) was migrated from Super User? I dont see this option in SO when closing questions.

There are at least 10 Questions posted in SO related to SharePoint. When will we have the option to move questions from So?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no *explicit* migration paths into (or out of) SharePoint Stack Exchange, yet. Those paths will not be defined until the site is out of public beta. We don't want to rush into shuffling posts around the network until the site has a chance to become established and graduates.

But if there is dire need, a moderator can move a post anywhere in the Network. Typically, overriding the established migration paths is used very sparingly. But a moderator over at Super User must have thought the migration of that question was advantageous or necessary.

Comment: Right - here's [how it went down](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/conversation/question-migration-from-super-user).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the mods over at SO have to make the moves.  Also that menu that comes up when you want to flag or close a question can be edited but probably won't be until after the Beta period is over.